# How to programmatically tell Celery to send all log messages to stdout or stderr?

Tags: python, logging, celery, python-logging

**How does one turn on celery logging programmatically?**

From the terminal, this works fine:

```
celery worker -l DEBUG
```

When I call `get_task_logger(__name__).debug('hello')`, I can see the message come up in the terminal. (stdout and stderr are being displayed)  I can even `import logging` and call `logger.info('hi')` and see that too. (both work)

However, while developing a task, I prefer to use a test module and call the task function directly rather than firing up a whole worker. But I can't see the log messages. I understand that Celery is redirecting everything to its internal apparatus, but I want to see the log messages on the stdout too.

**How do I tell Celery to send a copy of the log messages back to stdout?**

I've read a bunch of online articles about logging but it seems that a number of logging-related configuration vars from celery have been deprecated and it's unclear to me from the docs what is the supported path today.

**Here is an example module that creates a celery object and attempts to log output.  Nothing shows in the terminal.**

example **mymodule.py**

```
from celery import Celery
import logging
from celery.utils.log import get_task_logger

app = Celery('test')
app.config_from_object('myfile', True)

get_task_logger(__name__).warn('hello world')
logging.getLogger(__name__).warn('hello world 2')
```

**EDIT**
I know that I can add a handler to redirect some of the output back to the terminal by adding a handler

```
log = get_task_logger(__name__)
h = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)
log.addHandler(h)
```

But is there a "Celery way" to do this?  Maybe one that lets me also have the Celery formatted lines of text.

```
[2014-03-02 15:51:32,949: WARNING] hello world
```

Answer (score 13):

I have been looking at the same issue...

What seems to work best is to use the signal handler, according to http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/signals.html#after-setup-logger

In your `celery.py` file use:

```
from celery.signals import after_setup_logger
import logging


@after_setup_logger.connect()
def logger_setup_handler(logger, **kwargs ):
  my_handler = MyLogHandler()
  my_handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG) 
  my_formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s') #custom formatter
  my_handler.setFormatter(my_formatter)
  logger.addHandler(my_handler)

  logging.info("My log handler connected -> Global Logging")


if __name__ == '__main__':
  app.start()
```

then you can define `MyLogHandler()` as you wish.

To send the logs to STDOUT you should also be able to use (I have not tested it):

```
my_handler = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)
```